# ag-grid -- column grouping collapsed columns ignored when selecting or pasting or copying

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue, ag-grid-validation

how to select ,paste & copy collapsed data in column grouping in ag-grid?by default ag-grid ignoring collapsed columns . **i want collapsed columns also to be taken into account . Ms Excel has these feature of selecting collapsed columns also** . so how to implement same in ag-grid?**your text**

i want collapsed column data also to be added